# How do I format data arrays in the correct way React ChartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm running into some trouble trying to visualize data using the react version of ChartJS. I believe I'm aware of where the problem lies but after not being able to find anything online, I have no idea how to fix it. Basically, I am trying to create a doughnut chart which visualizes the amount of tasks in a specific stage (todo, in progress and completed). Here's my code:

```html
const STATUS_BUCKETS = {
  "ToDo": "ToDo",
  "In Progress": "Progress",
  "Completed": "Completed"
}

function DashboardCard06(props) {

  const chartData = {labels: [], datasets: []};
  for (const bucket in STATUS_BUCKETS) {
    const filteredStatusTasks = props.task.reduce((prev, current) => {
      if (current.status === STATUS_BUCKETS[bucket]) {
      return prev + 1; }
      else {
        return prev
      }
    }, 0);
    chartData.labels.push(bucket);
    chartData.datasets.push({
          data: [filteredStatusTasks],
          backgroundColor: [
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[500],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.blue[400],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[800],
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[600],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.blue[500],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[900],
          ],
          hoverBorderColor: tailwindConfig().theme.colors.white,
    })
  }



  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col col-span-full sm:col-span-6 xl:col-span-4 bg-white shadow-lg rounded-sm border border-slate-200">
      <header className="px-5 py-4 border-b border-slate-100">
        <h2 className="font-semibold text-slate-800">Stage</h2>
      </header>
      {/* Chart built with Chart.js 3 */}
      {/* Change the height attribute to adjust the chart height */}
      <DoughnutChart data={chartData} width={389} height={260} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The labels that I provide to ChartJS don't seem to be the problem but there is something with the datasets. For some reason, the code I wrote delivers 3 different arrays with seperated data points inside them (see screenshot).

[image]

Now, if I were to replace the data with some manually entered numbers like this:

```html
 chartData.labels.push(bucket);
    chartData.datasets.push({
          data: [5, 8, 13],
          backgroundColor: [
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[500],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.blue[400],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[800],
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[600],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.blue[500],
            tailwindConfig().theme.colors.indigo[900],
          ],
          hoverBorderColor: tailwindConfig().theme.colors.white,
    })
```

My datasets would look like this: [image]

Even though I now have 3 copies of the same line which is not the idea, apparently this is the way ChartJS wants the datasets to be formated, yet I have no idea how to achieve that with my own code. Is there anyone that knows how I can transform my own data into 1 array structured the way ChartJS expects it?

Thank you very much for your time and effort in advance. Looking forward to getting this fixed!

Kind regards,

Bram

EDIT: Chart configuration

```html
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  Chart, DoughnutController, ArcElement, TimeScale, Tooltip,
} from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';

// Import utilities
import { tailwindConfig } from '../utils/Utils';

Chart.register(DoughnutController, ArcElement, TimeScale, Tooltip);

function DoughnutChart({
  data,
  width,
  height
}) {

  const canvas = useRef(null);
  const legend = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: {
        cutout: '80%',
        layout: {
          padding: 24,
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        interaction: {
          intersect: false,
          mode: 'nearest',
        },
        animation: {
          duration: 500,
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        resizeDelay: 200,
      },
      plugins: [{
        id: 'htmlLegend',
        afterUpdate(c, args, options) {
          const ul = legend.current;
          if (!ul) return;
          // Remove old legend items
          while (ul.firstChild) {
            ul.firstChild.remove();
          }
          // Reuse the built-in legendItems generator
          const items = c.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(c);
          items.forEach((item) => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.style.margin = tailwindConfig().theme.margin[1];
            // Button element
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('btn-xs');
            button.style.backgroundColor = tailwindConfig().theme.colors.white;
            button.style.borderWidth = tailwindConfig().theme.borderWidth[1];
            button.style.borderColor = tailwindConfig().theme.colors.slate[200];
            button.style.color = tailwindConfig().theme.colors.slate[500];
            button.style.boxShadow = tailwindConfig().theme.boxShadow.md;
            button.style.opacity = item.hidden ? '.3' : '';
            button.onclick = () => {
              c.toggleDataVisibility(item.index, !item.index);
              c.update();
            };
            // Color box
            const box = document.createElement('span');
            box.style.display = 'block';
            box.style.width = tailwindConfig().theme.width[2];
            box.style.height = tailwindConfig().theme.height[2];
            box.style.backgroundColor = item.fillStyle;
            box.style.borderRadius = tailwindConfig().theme.borderRadius.sm;
            box.style.marginRight = tailwindConfig().theme.margin[1];
            box.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            // Label
            const label = document.createElement('span');
            label.style.display = 'flex';
            label.style.alignItems = 'center';
            const labelText = document.createTextNode(item.text);
            label.appendChild(labelText);
            li.appendChild(button);
            button.appendChild(box);
            button.appendChild(label);
            ul.appendChild(li);
          });
        },
      }],
    });
    return () => chart.destroy();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="grow flex flex-col justify-center">
      <div>
        <canvas ref={canvas} width={width} height={height}></canvas>
      </div>
      <div className="px-5 pt-2 pb-6">
        <ul ref={legend} className="flex flex-wrap justify-center -m-1"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DoughnutChart;
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to have only 1 dataset with 3 data (1 for each label) therefore I think the dataset definition should put outside of cycle of the labels.

Comment: Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/qBYXNJG Maybe can help.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer! I have structured the code according to your codepen and the data structure itself is fixed now! The chart receives a single dataset with all 3 data points in one array.  Thank you very much for that! The dataset and labels now look exactly as they are supposed to do. Unfortunately, the chart is still not outputting anything. Would you have any other idea what might be causing this? Cheers, Bram

Comment: The weird thing is that there are absolutely no errors in the console whatsoever. It almost seems like something is going wrong in the rendering part and not the data part.

Comment: can you publish the whole chart config ?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the chart configuration!

Comment: The options sounds ok but usually, when the is not drawing, means that the "data" is not correct. Do you have the possibility to publish the whole "data" structure?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure what you meant by the whole data structure but I have added the  structure of the chartData and the specific data that it contains. If you meant something else, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: What have you published as last element is your chartData? I don't think you are passing that object as data for the chart, correct?  I mean the object "{
  "data": {
    "labels": [....." I have played with your config in the codepen and it is working but I have a doubt (mentioned before)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean (object as in filteredStatusTasks, right?), however it's not really an object. If I log it, it's just an array of the amount of tasks I have in each bucket. I have included a screenshot of the console output if I log it. Other than logging it, I'm not aware how I can show you the structure of it.

Comment: I created a gist, maybe it's easier: https://gist.github.com/stockiNail/3363755c2e5a31955061187184bf604d