# React Apexchart Multi-Series Bar Chart

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I'm trying to make a multi-series bar chart (NOT A TIME SERIES) and I've finally figured it out but my bars are too thin because I have to render null values in other places in order to make the chart function correctly.

What I want are thicker bars. I have tried to change the barHeight as well, but then the rest of my bars are off the screen (refer to the last image)

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do?

Here is before

[image]

Here is after
[image]

I've had to modify my data source from this

```
"series": [
        {
            "name": "New York Times",
            "data": [
                5674
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CNET",
            "data": [
                2637
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Fox News",
            "data": [
                2524
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "The Best BBQ in St. Louis",
            "data": [
                2178
            ]
        },
        .....
    ],
```

to this

```
    series: [
      {
        name: "New York Times",
        data: [5674, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      },
      {
        name: "CNET",
        data: [null, 2637, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      },
      {
        name: "Fox News",
        data: [null, null, 2523, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      },
      {
        name: "The Best BBQ in St. Louis",
        data: [null, null, null, 2178, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      },
      ....
    ],
```

here is my chart code

```
    <Chart
      options={{
        chart: {
          type: "bar",
          height: 350,
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: data.labels,
        },
        colors: [
          "#808bf7",
          "#798ff4",
          "#6e95f0",
          "#6399eb",
          "#5b9ce8",
          "#52a2e3",
          "#49a7e1",
          "#43abde",
          "#3caedb",
          "#3ab1d9",
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          textAnchor: "start",
          style: {
            fontSize: "12px",
            fontFamily: "Nunito, Arial, sans-serif",
            fontWeight: 500,
            colors: [
              "#808BF7",
              "#798FF4",
              "#6E95F0",
              "#6399EB",
              "#5B9CE8",
              "#52A2E3",
              "#49A7E1",
              "#43ABDE",
              "#3CAEDB",
              "#3AB1D9",
            ],
          },
          background: {
            enabled: true,
            foreColor: "#fff",
            padding: 4,
            borderRadius: 2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: "#fff",
            opacity: 1,
            dropShadow: {
              enabled: false,
              top: 1,
              left: 1,
              blur: 1,
              color: "#000",
              opacity: 0.45,
            },
          },
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: "100%",
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
          intersect: true,
        },
      }}
      series={data.series}
      type="bar"
      height="500"
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in `plotOptions` add

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
   horizontal: true,
   barHeight: '20',
  },
},
```

**Basic Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/vo9xa4f8/57/

Comment: If you refer to the last image I posted, I said I did change the bar height but in doing so the bars started to disappear off my chart

Comment: Instead of percentages, have you tried putting it in px? or instead put less percentage, 75% for example

Comment: yup, i've tried PX and % values as well as no suffix. Same result. It seems to be with the fact that rendering a null value in place for where a value is makes the bar thinner by default because there are still x number of other bars that couldve been displayed

Comment: Also your JS fiddle is a one dimensional array of data vs the data i have provided is a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Check this posts link1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74984437/create-bar-chart-from-multidimensional-array-series-with-apexcharts-or-vueape  Link2: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73801255/how-do-i-format-data-arrays-in-the-correct-way-react-chartjs